# Finding pixel location of centroid in a region

Tags: matlab, image-processing, centroid, imshow

I have an image in Matlab where I am finding the all the centroids in it. There are multiple centroids in the image and I am using 'imellipse' to seclude one of them. I am trying to find the pixel location of one of centroids. Having the location pop-up in the command window of Matlab will be good enough.
Here is my code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton15.
function pushbutton15_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton15 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
A = imread('PET_MRI_Brain_Tumor.jpg');
Z = imshow(A)
Ibw = im2bw(A);
Ibw = imfill(Ibw,'holes');
Ilabel = bwlabel(Ibw);
stat = regionprops(Ilabel,'centroid');
imshow(Z); hold on;
for x = 1: numel(stat)
    plot(stat(x).Centroid(1),stat(x).Centroid(2),'bx');
end
e = imellipse(gca,[55 10 120 120])
BW = createMask(e,Z)
```

Here is the picture where I am trying to extrapolate the pixel location of the centroid marker.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0DP2.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For a question on Stack Overflow it is expected that you provide a clear description of what you want to achieve. A centroid is a multivariate mean, e.g. a mean position, but it is unclear the centroid of what exactly you are trying to determine, or how there can be multiple centroids in one image. It's good you included the image, but you have to describe it. What exactly in this image are you talking about, what is the feature you are interested in? Moreover, is your question about image analysis, or about programming your GUI?

Comment: Thanks for replying...The image is that of a brain with tumors and the tumors "weigh more than" the rest of the brain image (except in the middle). What I want to accomplish is locating the location of where the tumors are one at a time. This is in a GUI with a push-button but the output of the pixel location can be in the Matlab command window.

Comment: The difficult part that I cannont figure out is how to seclude just one at a time and determine it's location in the picture. The other thing is I cannot move the picture around because the points would then be meaningless

Comment: Do you want to localize the tumors automatically or by user interaction? What does "weigh more" mean precisely? Can you include a link to the data in a Matlab-readable format?

Comment: I want to be able to move the 'imellipse' over one of the crosshairs and then matlab would spit-out the location of the crosshair. The crosshair is marking the centroid of the tumor. So, I would be trying to use user interaction. I am really stumped on this so any type of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you need to implement the whole thing yourself. Have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html, I think that's almost exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot about that handle toolbox. Also, on a related note, are you aware of a function that will let me click on the image, draw a circle (it will be done with the mouse so will alway be an irregular shape) then have it display next to that image on another axes?

Comment: Have a look at `ginput` and `dragrect`.